# How can I revoke an external function on click of an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code:

```js
$(function(){ // ready

  function myfunc($el){
      $el.text("You clicked ..!");
  }

  $("div").click(myfunc($(this)));
  
})
```

```css
div{
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Click Here</div>
```

Why the text doesn't change after clicking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To pass a variable/argument, you need to do something like this to make that work

```
$("div").click(function(){myfunc($(this))});
```

Stack snippet

```js
$(function(){ // ready

  function myfunc($el){
      $el.text("You clicked ..!");
  }

  $("div").click(function(){myfunc($(this))});
  
})
```

```css
div{
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Click Here</div>
```

---

To make a simpler function call, you can do like this and make use of the event.

```js
$(function(){ // ready

  function myfunc(e){
      $(e.target).text("You clicked ..!");
  }

  $("div").click(myfunc);
  
})
```

```css
div{
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

div:hover{
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>Click Here</div>
```

Comment: @MartinAJ Added a 2nd option

Comment: @LGSon Yeah I seen that, but in reality it's nothing to do with `text()`. It is: `$el.closest("section").css("background-color", "#e1e1e1");`. Any idea?

Comment: @MartinAJ You can do `$(e.target)` to make it a jQuery object, updated my answer, and ... e.g. this should work: `$(e.target).closest("section").css("background-color", "#e1e1e1");`

Comment: Yeah got it .. Also (sorry for asking, I'm newbie in JS), can I set `ev` (or whatever) as the function parameter and then use `$(ev.target)`, right?

Comment: @MartinAJ Yes you can